# convert to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am learning jquery and would like to learn how to convert this server side code to jquery function. Any help is appreciated.

```
Protected Sub ChartstoDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChartstoDisplay.SelectedIndexChanged
    For i As Integer = 0 To ChartstoDisplay.Items.Count - 1
        If ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Selected Then
            ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Attributes.Add("style", "color:DarkGreen;")
        Else
            ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Attributes.Add("style", """")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried this to no avail.

```
function checkboxSelection() {          
    foreach (ListItem li in ChartstoDisplay.Items)
    {
        li.Attributes["class"] = "checkBoxListItems";
    }
    $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxListItems").each(
        function(intIndex) {
            if ($(this).find('input').attr('checked') === true)
                    $(this).attr.add("style","color:DarkGreen;");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? A `foreach` loop does not exist in JavaScript...

Comment: Why don't you start with learning javascript?

Comment: Obviously, the Javascript+JQuery code doesn't work like the Visual Basic snippet he posted - in other words: it doesn't make the checkBoxListItems green when checked.

To help, we(I) need more info: what are the contents of ChartstoDisplay.Items, and what is the HTML it is working on?

Comment: @zerkms, SO doesn't need more snarky comments. At least Felix gave some constructive feedback.

Comment: @davidethell: let's see if that constructive comment would be helpful for OP ;-)

Comment: try change functions. http://api.jquery.com/change

Comment: To be a little clearer, ChartstoDisplay is the id of the checkboxlist. I am trying to change the fontcolor of the text to DarkGreen when the item is checked. I currently do it through code behind which is the wrong method, thus the statement that I am learning Jquery/javascript in the fist sentence (zerkms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help from here and others here is the solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').change(
          function () {
              if ($('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked')) {
                  $(this).next().addClass("selected");
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonsshow").removeClass('buttonshide');
                  $("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                      $(this).prop("checked", true);
                      $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("selected");
                  });
              } else {
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonshide").removeClass('buttonsshow');
                  $(this).next().removeClass("selected");
                  $("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                      $(this).prop("checked", false);
                      $(this).siblings("label").removeClass("selected");
                  });
              }
          });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume ChartstoDisplay this is the combo box, and you want to change the class based on selection. [Jquery change](http://api.jquery.com/change)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("ChartstoDisplay").change(function () {
           $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("Selected") ;
                  });
           }).change();

});
```

Comment: Ravi, The ChartstoDisplay is a checkboxlist not a combobox.  I tried something like this to no avail too

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#ChartstoDisplay").click(function () {
              $("input checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                  $(this).attr('checked', ':checked');
              });
          }).click();

      });
    </script>